# R - is there a built-in function (or just a smart way) to retrieve the row with most minimal values from a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, comparison

I have a function which generates a data frame similar to this (slightly bigger, though) with accuracies of varies models fitted to a time series:

```
                       ME      RMSE       MAE        MPE      MAPE      MASE        
meanf        2.524524e-14 353.76903 301.17593 -82.164390 113.58707 2.3056530
naive       -5.714286e-02 253.88378 173.08571 -18.681301  50.61388 1.3250581
snaive      -1.081250e+02 179.92394 130.62500 -34.536282  41.42914 1.0000000
rwf         -5.714286e-02 253.88378 173.08571 -18.681301  50.61388 1.3250581
croston      4.320108e+01 383.23873 310.49928 -69.336872 108.94512 2.3770279
stlf        -4.462532e+00  82.74412  60.77570  -2.775185  17.55461 0.4652685 
ses         -3.289695e-01 250.34678 168.55694 -18.313167  49.35868 1.2903880
```

I want to retrieve the row with most minimal absolute values, e.g. the row for the stlf model above.

I have tried playing around with abs() and pmin(), but it returns a vector with the minimal value from each column, which is not what I want (unless one row has all the minimal values, but that's hardly ever the case).

I don't know if there is a built-in function to do this, or even just a smart way.

I would like a function to do the comparisons for me as I don't trust my eyes to always find the best fit just from looking at the dataframe.

Thanks!

Comment: You want the row that has the most number of column-wise smallest numbers?

Comment: do you want the row with the smallest absolute average value? Can you give us an example of what you would want given your dataset above?

Comment: Yes, as I wrote above, I'd like the stlf row above, because it has the largest number of minimum absolute values. That is, all of it's values except for the ME are smaller (in absolute terms) than the other ones.

Comment: When fitting a model, you want the constants to be as small as possible, which is why I'm trying to pick out the row with most (column-wise) minimal values

Answer (score 0):

**If** I understand your question correctly, then you can get what you want using a two step process. First, we get some data

```
    m = read.table(textConnection("ME      RMSE       MAE        MPE      MAPE      MASE        
meanf        2.524524e-14 353.76903 301.17593 -82.164390 113.58707 2.3056530
naive       -5.714286e-02 253.88378 173.08571 -18.681301  50.61388 1.3250581
snaive      -1.081250e+02 179.92394 130.62500 -34.536282  41.42914 1.0000000
rwf         -5.714286e-02 253.88378 173.08571 -18.681301  50.61388 1.3250581
croston      4.320108e+01 383.23873 310.49928 -69.336872 108.94512 2.3770279
stlf        -4.462532e+00  82.74412  60.77570  -2.775185  17.55461 0.4652685 
ses         -3.289695e-01 250.34678 168.55694 -18.313167  49.35868 1.2903880"))
```

1. Find the minimum absolute values in each column

   ```
   mins = apply(abs(m), 2, which.min)
   ```
2. Tabulate the results, sort and extract

   ```
   rname = names(which.max(table(mins)))
   rownames(m)[as.numeric(rname)]
   ```

Comment: why not even more simple: `apply(abs(m), 1, min)` ?

Comment: The data frame I end up with presently has 14 rows and 7 columns, so there's going to be 7 (not necessarily unique) minimum values, and I want to pick out the row (including it's rowname) with the highest number of those 7 minimum values.

Comment: @cgillespie, It is your code that gives me a 2 x 2 table called "mins" - I guess it counts the number of times each row has some sort of minimum and then counts the number of times each of those numbers show up.

Comment: Very simple example: `m <- rbind(c(9,1,-1,0,1), c(2,1,2,-3,-6), c(-8,-1,5,2,1))
rownames(m) <- c("a", "b", "c") ` - Now, I'd like to get the answer `"a"` or `"a" 9 1 -1 0 1`, but your revised method returns `"b"`

Comment: It works now - I have yet to try the solution using `order`as posted above by @James

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting the `order` of each column and count the rows to see which has the most minimal values:

```
rowSums(sapply(abs(x),order)==1)
[1] 1 0 0 0 0 3 2
```

To can use `order` on this the reorder your original data by smallest:

```
x[order(rowSums(sapply(abs(x),order)==1),decreasing=TRUE),]
                   ME      RMSE      MAE        MPE      MAPE      MASE
stlf    -4.462532e+00  82.74412  60.7757  -2.775185  17.55461 0.4652685
ses     -3.289695e-01 250.34678 168.5569 -18.313167  49.35868 1.2903880
meanf    2.524524e-14 353.76903 301.1759 -82.164390 113.58707 2.3056530
naive   -5.714286e-02 253.88378 173.0857 -18.681301  50.61388 1.3250581
snaive  -1.081250e+02 179.92394 130.6250 -34.536282  41.42914 1.0000000
rwf     -5.714286e-02 253.88378 173.0857 -18.681301  50.61388 1.3250581
croston  4.320108e+01 383.23873 310.4993 -69.336872 108.94512 2.3770279
```

Comment: Neat, but are you missing a abs in the sapply

Comment: @csgillespie Thanks, I missed that in the question